# Authentication Glitch

Tags: system-installation, updates, appcenter

When I go in and try and do the os update it won't let me put in my password it keeps glitching so fast that I can't enter the password to allow the update. Anyone encounter this?

Comment: So the window appears, then disappears? What if you go to a terminal and try this: `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade`?

Comment: The same ploblem did you got it fixed?

Answer (score 0):

Try this out

```
sudo chmod 7755 /usr/lib/policykit-1/polkit-agent-helper-1
```